# Play Framework & Scala: Problems with FakeRequest & JSON POST in unit test

Tags: json, unit-testing, scala, playframework

I have spent too much time trying to debug the following issue but I am not sure where the problem is occurring.

Issue: Getting `400 Bad Request, Invalid Json` as response with following exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: [B@6ee503c9; line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:164) ~[jackson-databind.jar:2.2.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2931) ~[jackson-databind.jar:2.2.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2846) ~[jackson-databind.jar:2.2.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1569) ~[jackson-databind.jar:2.2.2]
    at play.api.libs.json.JacksonJson$.parseJsValue(JsValue.scala:480) ~[play-json_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
    at play.api.libs.json.Json$.parse(Json.scala:27) ~[play-json_2.10.jar:2.2.0]
```

Method to be tested in my controller:

```
  def createArticle(id: String) =
      Action.async(parse.json) { implicit request =>
        (request.body \ "content").asOpt[String].map {
            ............
            ............
        }.getOrElse(BadRequest("Invalid request body"))
      }
```

Corresponding Unit Test:

```
  "create article" in {
    running(FakeApplication()) {
      val postJson = Json.obj("content" -> "article content")

      val result = resource.createArticle(ARTICE_ID)(FakeRequest(POST, controllers.routes.ArticleResource.create(ARTICLE_ID).url).withJsonBody(postJson).withHeaders(CONTENT_TYPE -> "application/json").run

      status(result) must equalTo OK
    }
  }
```

I read the discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework/GU2qeQ9naaA/Uf9fsBMxt3IJ) but none of the suggestions there helped.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44778488/invalid-json-no-content-to-map-due-to-end-of-input-when-using-play-body-parser

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems, but didn't solve them so far (elegantly, anyway..). As my environment was java instead of scala, I can just give a hunch. I think that it's possible that when you send post it's done asynchronously (Action.async at your create article method), so you'd possibly need to wait at test code result before trying to see if it's OK.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and the solution is pointed [here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/2096). In my case it was because I using `response.asJson()` twice, and as described by @jroper

> Considering that the body of an HTTP response is a stream, and not
>   something that you want to necessarily buffer in memory, then it makes
>   sense that accessing the body twice (regardless of what format you are
>   accessing the body in) would not be supported.

Answer (score 0):

Try instantiating your request inside the method definition.

This is how it's working for me (example using POST with JSON body and result as JSON):

```
"process" should {
    "should be valid" in {
 val request = FakeRequest(POST, "/").withJsonBody(Json.parse("""      {  
     "id":1,
     "name":"prod 1",
     "price":55.55
  }"""))

  val result: Future[Result] = controller.process.apply(request)      
  val json = contentAsJson(result)            

  status(result) must be(CREATED)
  (json \ "id").as[Int] mustBe 1

// .. more assertions and rest of code ...
```

Here the code deals with a JsValue and query it's nodes to check if the returned values are matching the desired mock data output