# Invalid Json: No content to map due to end-of-input when using play body parser

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm trying to test a controller method that attempts to parse JSON sent in the request:

```
  def addRoomToProfileForTime = Action.async(parse.json[AddRoomToProfileForTimeRequest]) { request =>
    profileService.addRoomToProfileForTime(request.body.roomId, request.body.profileId, request.body.timeRange).value.map {
      case Xor.Right(_)  => Ok
      case Xor.Left(err) => BadRequest(Json.toJson(err))
    }
  }
```

This is the case class that represents the request:

```
final case class AddRoomToProfileForTimeRequest(
  roomId: Int,
  profileId: Int,
  timeRange: TimeRange
)

implicit val addRoomToProfileForTimeRequestFormat:Format[AddRoomToProfileForTimeRequest] = Json.format
```

This code works as expected with I make a request like so:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"roomId":3,"profileId":1,"timeRange":{"id":1,"fromTime":"2000-01-01T01:01","toTime":"2000-01-01T02:01"}}' http://localhost:9000/api/profiles/addRoomToProfileForTime
```

But I'm trying to write a test for this method (note that I am using macwire for dependency injection, hence cannot use `WithApplication`:

```
"add a room to profile for time" in new TestContext {
  val roomId = 1
  val profileId = 1
  val from = "2000-01-01T01:01"
  val to = "2000-01-01T02:01"
  val requestJson = Json.obj(
    "roomId"    -> roomId,
    "profileId" -> profileId,
    "timeRange" -> Json.obj(
      "id"       -> 1,
      "fromTime" -> from,
      "toTime"   -> to
    )
  )

  implicit val system = ActorSystem()
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  val fakeReq = FakeRequest(Helpers.POST, "api/profiles/addRoomToProfileForTime")
    .withHeaders(CONTENT_TYPE -> "application/json")
    .withJsonBody(requestJson)
  val result = profileController.addRoomToProfileForTime()(fakeReq).run

  val content  = contentAsString(result)
  println(content)
  status(result) must equalTo(OK)
}
```

However, this test fails with a Bad Request from Play:

```
<body>                                             
    <h1>Bad Request</h1>                                

    <p id="detail">
        For request 'POST api/profiles/addRoomToProfileForTime' [Invalid Json: No content to map due to end-of-input at [Source: akka.util.ByteIterator$ByteArrayIterator$$anon$1@37d14073; line: 1, column: 0]]
    </p>

</body>
```

If I parse the JSON with `request.body.asJson` the method behaves as expected. It's only using the body parser method above that I get this error.

Comment: I have similar issue. Unfortunately, even using `request.body.asJson` in controller has not helped in my case...

Comment: I have another very similar project with a nearly identical controller method, except I am using Guice for dependency injection. [This example](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTestingWithScalaTest#Unit-Testing-EssentialAction) works exactly as expected.

Comment: I have reported an issue for that: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/7877 and created test repository to reproduce this issue: https://github.com/Abrasha/playframework-issue-example

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The short answer is: on your `FakeRequest` in your controller test use the `withBody` method instead of `withJsonBody`.

I had this issue as well, and I embarrassingly spent hours on it until I figured it out. The long answer is that `FakeRequest`'s `withJsonBody` returns a `FakeRequest[AnyContentAsJson]`, and since your controller is expecting a `JsValue` (**not** an `AnyContentAsJson`), when you call `apply()` on your action it fails to match this apply method, which is the one you want:

```
def apply(request: Request[A]): Future[Result]
```

and *instead* hits this apply method:

```
def apply(rh: RequestHeader): Accumulator[ByteString, Result]
```

and thus since you're not then passing any Bytes to the Accumulator, you get the unexpected `end-of-input` error message you're getting.

Comment: Wow thank you so much. I also have just spent hours on this. This problem occurred for me during upgrade from play 2.5.x to 2.6.x

Comment: See https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/7877 discussion

Comment: Why `FakeRequest[AnyContentAsJson]` maps to `RequestHeader`?

Answer (score 0):

Another reason can be not setting `Content-Length` in Postman application. By mistake I had disabled it, and forgot to enable it. [image].