# Play returning bad request if I use parse.json in Action Composition

Tags: playframework-2.6, play-json

I have this `Action`. It works fine

```
def newQuestion = silhouette.SecuredAction.async /*(parse.json)*/ { 
    implicit request => { 
      println("got request with body:" + request.body)
      println("got content header headers "+request.request.headers.get("Content-Type"))
          val body:AnyContent = request.body
...
}
```

I have tested it with the following unit test case

```
"newQuestion" should {
    "should return error if the size of the body in the request is more than the maximum allowed size" in {
      val sizeConfig = Map("maxAllowedBodySize"-> 10)
      val maxBodySizeConfig = Map("codingJedi" -> sizeConfig )
      val newConfiguration = Configuration.from(maxBodySizeConfig)
      val testEnv = new QuestionsControllerSpecTestEnv(Some(newConfiguration),components)
      val body =
        s"""
           |{
           | "practice-question":{
           | "description": "some description",
           | "hints": ["hint1","hint2"],
           | "image": ["image1 data","image2 data","image3 data"],
           | "success-test": "success test",
           | "fail-test": "fail test",
           | "tags": ["${testEnv.tag}","${testEnv.tag}"],
           | "title":"some title",
           | "answer": "some answer",
           | "references":["ref1","ref2"]
           | }
           |}
        """.stripMargin

      val jsonBody = Json.parse(body)

      println("jsBody is "+jsonBody)

      val request = new FakeRequest(FakeRequest("POST","ws/questions/new-question")).withHeaders(CONTENT_TYPE -> "application/json").withAuthenticator(testEnv.testEnv.loginInfo)(testEnv.testEnv.fakeEnv).withBody(AnyContentAsJson(jsonBody))

      println("outgoing request is "+request)
      println("headers "+request.headers)
      println("body "+request.body)


      val response = testEnv.questionsController.newQuestion(request)
        val responseBody = contentAsJson(response)             println(s"received response body ${responseBody}")
        val result = (responseBody \ "result").get.as[String]
        val additionalInfo = (responseBody \ "additional-info").get.as[String]
        result mustBe "error"
        additionalInfo mustBe components.messagesApi("error.entityTooLarge")(components.langs.availables(0))
    }
  }
```

But when I try to add `parse.json` to the Action

```
def newQuestion = silhouette.SecuredAction.async (parse.json) {...}
```

The test case fails because `Play` returns `Bad Request`

```
Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Bad Request</title>
        <style>
            html, body, pre {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                font-family: Monaco, 'Lucida Console', monospace;
                background: #ECECEC;
            }
            h1 {
                margin: 0;
                background: #AD632A;
                padding: 20px 45px;
                color: #fff;
                text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
                border-bottom: 1px solid #9F5805;
                font-size: 28px;
            }
            p#detail {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 15px 45px;
                background: #F6A960;
                border-top: 4px solid #D29052;
                color: #733512;
                text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.3);
                font-size: 14px;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #BA7F5B;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Bad Request</h1>

        <p id="detail">
            For request 'POST ws/questions/new-question' [Invalid Json: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: akka.util.ByteIterator$ByteArrayIterator$$anon$1@37af24cb; line: 1, column: 0]]
        </p>

    </body>
</html>
; line: 1, column: 2]
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Bad Request</title>
        <style>
            html, body, pre {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                font-family: Monaco, 'Lucida Console', monospace;
                background: #ECECEC;
            }
            h1 {
                margin: 0;
                background: #AD632A;
                padding: 20px 45px;
                color: #fff;
                text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
                border-bottom: 1px solid #9F5805;
                font-size: 28px;
            }
            p#detail {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 15px 45px;
                background: #F6A960;
                border-top: 4px solid #D29052;
                color: #733512;
                text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,.3);
                font-size: 14px;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #BA7F5B;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Bad Request</h1>

        <p id="detail">
            For request 'POST ws/questions/new-question' [Invalid Json: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: akka.util.ByteIterator$ByteArrayIterator$$anon$1@37af24cb; line: 1, column: 0]]
        </p>

    </body>
</html>
; line: 1, column: 2]
```

The `json` I am sending looks ok.

```
{"practice-question":{"description":"some description","hints":["hint1","hint2"],"image":["image1 data","image2 data","image3 data"],"success-test":"success test","fail-test":"fail test","tags":["coding-javascript-form","coding-javascript-form"],"title":"some title","answer":"some answer","references":["ref1","ref2"]}}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid Json: No content to map due to end-of-input when using play body parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44778488/invalid-json-no-content-to-map-due-to-end-of-input-when-using-play-body-parser)

Comment: this article has very good explanation of what is happening - https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/7877